# abstract class and arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I don't understand some lines on this code

```
public abstract class subject{
```

The class is abstract so `subject` is a super class

```
    public subject() {
```

And this is a constructor?

Like inside this constructor is passed on to sub classes?

```
observers = new ArrayList<IOserver> ();
```

Here I have no idea.

Comment: ArrayList<IOserver> : Read about generics

Comment: A class can be declared `public class ArrayList<T>`, allowing you to use `T` as a type in that class. It's a type parameter which lets you specify a type to use for that specific instance. That `ArrayList` uses type `IOObserver`.  `T` is now seen as `IOObserver` in class `ArrayList` for that instance. Google *java generics* to find out more.

Comment: Google Java generics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is passed on to the subclass as a constrained. The observers variable is initialized within the constructor, but I don't see it declared.

Like:

```
ArrayList<IOserver> observers = new ArrayList<IOserver> ();
```

Comment: hello do you know the when we need to use keyword protected infront of int? like what's the difference between int level; and protected int level; ?

Comment: The default >>> int level;  >>>> is set to package access

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html